# I found a wiki tag that I think is missing some information

Tags: discussion, questions, tag-wiki

I have not spotted any 'Guidelines' for editing the wiki tags so far and I'm too afraid to edit the wiki tag without having any guidelines. Have I missed the email we all got with the Guidelines for wiki tag editing or did I just not spot it anywhere?

Comment: there is a blog post about tag wikis: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/ also search for [wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki) might give you guidance or over at MSE [wiki guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki+guidelines)